# How to Hide First level cascading Parameter Dynamically

Tags: java, eclipse, reporting, birt

I have a case where i want to hide first level parameter in a cascading parameter Group.I will pass that argument as part of url(ie.as querystring?).Now i created two parameters under cascading parameter group(ie:officecode and empno).If user is passing officecode parameter through url(it means user is not admin),then i want to hide first level parameter (ie officecode) and directly load all the empno corresponding to that office.If user is not passing officecode as part of url(it means user is admin and want to show all the offices),then i want show both of the parameters in Parameter dailog.Or is any other way to handle this scenario??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically hide a parameter by adding this script under `getDefaultValueList:`

```
reportContext.getHttpServletRequest().getParameter("outerParameter")!=null?reportContext.getDesignHan
dle().findParameter("outerParameter").hidden = true:null
```

This checks whether outerParameter was filled through the servlet. If so, it hides it, if not, it gets shown.

In the same manner, you can check in the lower level parameter whether the upper level has been filled, and if so, pass on the value.

The url would be something like `www.website.com/birt/run?__report=reportname.rptdesign&outerParameter=specifiedValue` .